# HLS Discontinuity Manifest Playback issues, HEVC, fragmented mp4s

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, tvos

I am trying do a playback test with content stitched together in a HLS manifest using the #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag. Im testing on the AppleTV 4k with the VLC player and a hlsjs player with Safari on my MacOS (https://players.akamai.com/players/hlsjs)

I get playback issues when my player hits the first discontinuity section in both players. And im not sure how to further debug the issue. The VLC player just exits, the hlsjs player stops playback. I don't get any errors in the javascript console. The hlsjs player does display stats beside the player. The only hint I get is segment lenght is 5s up until it stops, then it says `No segment length found`

The encoding parameters are HEVC, 2pass CVBR, 30fps, Color format is yuv420p, The resolution UHD. This is the same for both pieces of content to keep things simple for this test. I'm outputting mp4s, then fragmenting them with mp4fragment (because the encodes are HEVC). I create my HLS package with Bento mp4dash with the --hls flag. IDR frame locations are variable.

I haven't found an off the shelf tool that will automate creating the discontinuity manifests... so I've resorted to manually compiling them together with the outputs of mp4dash. I suspect this is where I'm causing an issue. To further eliminate variables I've removed the Audio and the I-frame playlists. I also intend to use multiple variants, but for now I have just one for testing.

For this test the two pieces of content are split up with multiple discontinuity tags, starting where they left off based off the segment byteranges produced by mp4dash. If I had to guess, I would say the byteranges and extinf durations are determined by the IDR frame locations. Again I copied the segments from seperate manifests produced by mp4dash, The only extra thing I did was added the #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY #EXT-X-MAP tags with the copied segments. You can see (below) the first section of segments is 20s long. The player buffers and plays that without issue, then stops at the 20s mark. The original manifests and source mp4s playback fine in VLC.

My top Media playlist looks like this

```
#EXTM3U
# Created with Bento4 mp4-dash.py, VERSION=2.0.0-639
#
#EXT-X-VERSION:6

# Media Playlists

# Video
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=10521553,BANDWIDTH=18658978,CODECS="hev1.1.6.H150.90",RESOLUTION=3840x2160,FRAME-RATE=30.000
video-hev1-1.m3u8
```

My video-hev1-1.m3u8 variant playlist looks like this

```
#EXTM3U
# Created with Bento4 mp4-dash.py, VERSION=2.0.0-639
#
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="primary_15k_f.mp4",BYTERANGE="3648@0"
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9948641@3648
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9544542@9952409
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9585878@19496951
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9089581@29082829
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="secondary_9k_f.mp4",BYTERANGE="4146@0"
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:10604765@4146
secondary_9k_f.mp4
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="primary_15k_f.mp4",BYTERANGE="3648@0"
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9472631@38172410
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9660971@47645041
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9216628@57306012
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:1.0333333333333334,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:2410118@66522640
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:4903619@68932758
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:6451712@73836377
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:6902254@80288089
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="secondary_9k_f.mp4",BYTERANGE="4146@0"
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9400376@10731998
secondary_9k_f.mp4
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="primary_15k_f.mp4",BYTERANGE="3648@0"
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:2488589@87190343
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:2210423@89678932
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:2683935@91889355
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:2757832@94573290
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:2493162@97331122
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:2.433333333333333,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1055535@99824284
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1649392@100879819
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1691817@102529211
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1685144@104221028
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1664326@105906172
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1452046@107570498
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1513264@109022544
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:1587230@110535808
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:0.4666666666666667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:248625@112123038
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:10469982@112371663
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9538639@122841645
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9354339@132380284
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="secondary_9k_f.mp4",BYTERANGE="4146@0"
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9493058@20260000
secondary_9k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:3.533333333333333,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:6569724@29880365
secondary_9k_f.mp4
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="primary_15k_f.mp4",BYTERANGE="3648@0"
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9230273@141734623
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9389622@150964896
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9299430@160354518
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:9413868@169653948
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:2.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:4110225@179067816
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:8504561@183178041
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:8836491@191682602
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:7950448@200519093
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:7841691@208469541
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:8058588@216311232
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:8706054@224369820
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:8890875@233075874
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:8374564@241966749
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXTINF:2.2666666666666666,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:3758510@250341313
primary_15k_f.mp4
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

If my manifests are in good order, my next thing to eliminate for testing is variable IDR frame locations, then I'll try a test with CBR encodes. Additionally perhaps this doesn't work with HEVC fragmented mp4s?